# Adobe Illustrator - Is there a way to disable a object ability to overlap with an other object -- To help allign objects?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

Like what the title says, basically is there a way to disable a object ability to overlap with another object especially when moving?  If not any ideas what would be a workaround for me?  In this case I am trying to move the circle so it perfectly touches those two lines and so I can make a nice circular curve.

*So the story to this is that I make diagrams, charts and other technical stuff... Perhaps like a blue print, an layout, a design, a side for a 3d print, perhaps something to be import into blender, etc... thus why I choice to do it with vector graphics and scalability is another important thing as well.  The project basically have to be prefect or very close to and is typically heavy on math and everything is dependent on each other.  So this is not like a typical art work that doesn't really matter it does.  For example, the closest to art I design is logos and websites, like say an business pays me to do a logo for them, the scalability is key as it needs to look good on a website but also on proportionally a bulletin board so it might be 100x difference.  Lets say as a hobby I am designing a path layout for a game map, on the scale of the diagram a slight imperfection may be fine however if zoom in and enlarge to the point that where you are walking around etc...  You will see it and wouldn't look fine.*

*There has always been this problem which I could never figure out, like how do I get an object to touch two object perfectly, sometimes there is a solution like playing around with a small region and rotating it so that everything is a 90* degrees sometimes there is a no clear cut way and if it is possible it wastes so much time. The easiest thing would be to just move the object until it couldn't anymore just like in real life.  In the screenshot I am trying to align up a circle to those two lines on the outside underline in blue, one of them is straight while the other is a curve.  Mathematically it should be possible and is super easy to gasp. Any ideas?  Since the line is curve, I have no idea on how to even calculate the length of the line and the angle to center the circle for it to be prefect.
I begin to use AI instead of Inkscape due to AI has better snapping and aligning features to make things prefect but I could never figure this out and I am have never been able to find anything on this.  Are these problems just problems of vector image editors in general?*

[image]

Comment: There's nothing In Illustrator to prevent any object overlapping another. And there is no no "collision detection" for curves in Illustrator. AstuteGraphics.com offers the ColliderScribe plugin though. It's not free, but there is a free trial. Or.. draw a rectangle, then use the corner rounding to add your curve and cut the path where you need.

Comment: If mathematical accuracy is important to you, then Illustrator or even other similar vector software is not really the right kind of software. You could technically place an object at a 90 degree angle to touch circle, and rotate it, but circles in vector applications are based on Bézier paths, which can only be used to create an approximation of a circle - not mathematically perfect circles. If you then rotate the object, it will likely no longer line up exactly with the edge of the circle. TBH you are probably better to use actual CAD software for something like this.

Comment: @BillyKerr Billy, I believe you are right mostly. I look up the different CAD programs and I thought all of them were like blender and fusion 3d but I found LibreCAD and that fits my needs at least for drawing proposes.  No idea on how to make different sections like different colors but I could probably export it.

Comment: Thanks....  I just saw it not that long ago and it didn't occurred to me.... I know Blender but I wouldn't use blender and so I didn't have that thought on my own.